# Is it possible to adjust Windows 10 notification click area

Tags: windows-10, notifications, action-center

For a long time, I have been frustrated with Windows 10 notification popups.

It seems that when the popup is showing, the area that it consumes is in fact larger than the notification itself. This means if you try to click on something behind the notification, the notification will block that click even though it is outside of the visible notification.

Is it possible to amend the invisible area of the popup so that it matches the visible area, and works around this frustration?

Comment: The size of the notification is not adjustable. I use everything in windowed mode and can deal with all notifications

Comment: I have V1903 running (6 months now) and Notifications (a) remain not adjustable in size and (b) seems like the same size to me (and that may depend on screen scaling - 125% for me)

Comment: I have the exact same problem. It is highly annoying. Another annoying thing is that when you receive multiple updates from the same source they show one by one. When you click one away, the next one pops up etc. They should be grouped or something, like '10 new updates from xxx' or something.

Comment: Same issue here. Do you know if there is already a bug report in Microsoft's Feedback hub?